# Update a label when scrolling in my UICollectionView

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, ios9, uicollectionviewlayout

I have a calendar that contains each month in a collection view. As you scroll down it shows you each month with the days as a grid (so it looks like a calendar) with padding between each month.

I'd like to update a label at the top of the screen to change to the month you're correctly focused on. So as you scroll, when you cross some point in the screen, it changes from one month to another at the top.

For example I'm at the top and the label says 'January', and I scroll down to the point where I'm in February (part of January might still be visible above, part of March might be visible below), but I want February to appear on the label. Maybe it's some imaginary line of demarkation that I designate that causes the label to update.

Is something like this even possible? Where would I start?

Thanks!

Comment: look through the [UICollectionView Delegate](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UICollectionViewDelegate_protocol/index.html) class reference. Something like `collectionView:willDisplayCell:forItemAtIndexPath:` could work. CollectionViews are also a subclass of UIScrollView. So check out that [class reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIScrollViewDelegate_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/UIScrollViewDelegate) also.

Comment: Basically you want a function that get's called when the user scrolls or when a new item is visible. The function from UIScrollViewDelegate that detects continuous scrolling is very inefficient. The function from UICollectionViewDelegate that is fired when a new item is visible will require some maths to figure out when to update the label.

Comment: ok thanks! appreciate it :)

Answer (score 0):

Sure enough, the comments here got me exactly where I needed to be. Thanks so much for your help!

```
func scrollViewDidScroll(scrollView: UIScrollView) {
     let offsetY = scrollView.contentOffset.y
     let contentHeight = scrollView.contentSize.height
     let month = ((Int( (offsetY) / (contentHeight / 12))+1))
     //then just do what I need with 'month'
}
```